# What options are available for improving the appearance of a concrete porch?

Tags: concrete, patio, tiling

[image]

We have been looking to do something with our entrance patio flooring. We have some options to have it re-layered with concrete, but we would like something that is better looking and have considered tiling.
Is tiling a good option or are there other alternatives - we are worries about the "slip factor" with tiles, especially with snow/ice.
Is there a specific type of tile cement that must be used for outside?
I know this may be subjective, but just looking for ideas where some have had success.

Comment: Another option is outdoor carpeting. It quick, and relatively inexpensive. And, you can change it easily when you tire of it.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to apply stone veneer to the faces and top of the steps, making it look like stone steps. I've considered doing that with mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are to "re-layer" with more concrete you will lose some vertical space up against the house.  I've read 2 inches is the minimum for this procedure.  It looks like you have some vertical space to spare judging by the current distance from the patio to your door, but if your porch is enclosed you could effectively shrink your space.  Keep that in mind if you're a tall guy like me - every inch from the ceiling counts.

Another option you didn't list is to grind the existing surface down.  You would be able to level out rough spots, such as the one by your bench, polish the surface, and add some color with a stain.  There also does not appear to be any cracks so polishing would work well.  This may not ameliorate the "slip-factor," however, but would likely be a more solid option than re-layering, and potentially less prone to cracking down the line.